# Why are Chinese string lengths different in C++ and Python?

Tags: python, c++

For example:

```
s = “兰蔻面膜”
```

In Python, its length is:

```
>>> len(“兰蔻面膜”)
4
```

But in C++, len=12 as below:

```
cout<< s.length()<<endl;
12
```

Why is that? I am simply checking the  length of Chinese string in c++ IDE, and found its length is 12. The 's' has 4 characters.

Comment: Actually in c++, its length is 12.

Comment: I imagine number of symbols vs number of bytes required to encode the symbols

Comment: We have no idea what `s` is...

Comment: Should be `std::wstring s = L"兰蔻面膜";` which length is `4`.

Comment: @康桓瑋 it works in this case but not all. Because not all Unicode characters are represented by 1 `wchar_t`

Comment: `len("兰蔻面膜".encode("utf8"))` is 12.

Comment: @phuclv It should, and does work on GNU C, which has `sizeof(wchar_t) == 4`. Although unfortunately it doesn't work on MSVC, but I guess OP is not using MSVC because usually windows don't have utf-8 as default encoding right?

Comment: @yyyy try something like `L"‍"`, `L"‍‍‍"`, `L"‍❤️‍‍"`, `L""`, `L"Å"`, `L"각"`, `L"நி"`, `L"षि"`, `L""`, `L"❤️"`, `L"é"`... to see if any of them has length = 1 even when `sizeof(wchar_t) == 4`. UTF-32 doesn't mean fixed-length characters

Comment: @phuclv `L"Å"` could have length 1 (if codepoint U+00C5 has been used)? (I hexdumped your sample and see you used an A and a ring separately. How underhanded...) ;-)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat that's possible after [normalization](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/), but only a few characters have such equivalence, mostly Latin letters. Lots of characters are composed of multiple code points and you can't count the code units to get the string length